# How do I fix this Count statement inside my Linq to Sql code?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have the following Linq-to-SQL query.  On line #5 I'm trying to get the number of records from my Packages table where the conditions listed in my Where statement are satisfied.  I think everything is correct in this code except for line #5.  What did I do wrong?

```
var Overage = from s in db.Subscriptions
    join p in db.Packages on s.UserID equals p.UserID
    where 
      s.SubscriptionType != "PayAsYouGo" && 
      (s.CancelDate == null || s.CancelDate >= day) && 
      s.StartDate <= day && p.DateReceived <= day && 
      (p.DateShipped == null || p.DateShipped >= day)
    let AverageBoxSize = (p.Height * p.Length * p.Width) / 1728
    let ActiveBoxCount = p.Count()
    select new
    {
      p,
      AverageBoxSize,
      ActiveBoxCount,
      s.Boxes
    };
```

The error message is "Unknown method Count() of Foo.Data.Package"

**EDIT  Here's an example to accompany my question:**

Subscription Table:

```
UserID | Boxes
001      5
002      25
003      5
```

Boxes is the max number each user is permitted under his or her subscription

Packages Table

```
UserID | PackageID | Height | Length | Width
001      00001       10       10       10
001      00002       10       10       10
001      00003       20       10       10
003      00004       10       20       20
003      00005       10       10       10
```

Desired Query Result

```
UserID | Boxes | Box Count | Average Box Size
001      5           3           1,333
003      5           2           2,500
```

User 002 does not appear because the Where clause excludes that user

Comment: Yes, what did you do wrong? Is there an error?

Comment: What does running this yield? Does it yield an error, 0, 1, ... ?

Comment: Sorry about that.  I forgot to put the text of the error message in my question.  Fixed now.

Comment: P is an instance of you Package object not a collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments on Ryan's answer, this might be want you want:

```
var Overage = from s in db.Subscriptions
    join p in db.Packages on s.UserID equals p.UserID
    where 
      s.SubscriptionType != "PayAsYouGo" && 
      (s.CancelDate == null || s.CancelDate >= day) && 
      s.StartDate <= day && p.DateReceived <= day && 
      (p.DateShipped == null || p.DateShipped >= day)
    select new
    {
      p,
      AverageBoxSize = (p.Height * p.Length * p.Width) / 1728,
      ActiveBoxCount = db.Packages.Where(x => x.UserID == p.UserID).Count(),
      s.Boxes
    }
```

Comment: In reading the various comments I think my mistake is that I need to group the results by UserID.  Is that what your ActiveBoxCount line does? If so I'll need to fix my average size formula too so that it sums the product of the dimensions.  And I probably cannot select 'p' without aggregating all of the other columns of p (which is OK since I no longer need p).

Comment: You would need to group on all the properties you currently return in that case, im not sure that is possible on the `s.Boxes` collection

Answer (score 0):

P is not a collection. It should read:  let ActiveBoxCount = db.Packages.Count()

Comment: @Ryan. Thanks.  The count that I need is actually per UserID.  But db.Packages.Count() would give me the total count across all users, right?

Comment: @Magnus Good thought but that won't work.  s.Boxes tells me the max number of boxes the user is allowed to have according to the subscription table.  I'm trying to count how many each user actually has according to the packages table.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easiest to replace your Let line with something like -

```
Group <columns> By UserId into summary = Group 
Aggregate x in summary Into ActiveBoxCount = x.Count
```